# Is there a way I can compare code in an old Xcode project with a new Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a developer who has been working on an old Xcode project for me.  Is there a simple way I can compare files in his new Xcode project to the ones in the new Xcode project to quickly see which changes he's done and how the old code has changed? He's be procrastinating and finally i have twisted his arm to send me the new Xcode project.  He claims that the old code was rubbish, including the old coder too, so I'd like to see if he's actually done any changes to the old guy's project or is just plain and simple, 'a talker'.

Comment: `FileMerge` app compares two files and shows what are the differences in the contents of both the files.

Answer (score 9):

Sure, use the "diff" command (from a terminal window).

If the two projects are in folders "old-project" and "new-project", respectively, you would do something like:

```
diff -r old-project new-project
```

The "-r" will recursively compare corresponding files in subdirectories.

ps. this should also be a wake-up call to you that's it's time to put your project into some kind of version control system (such as svn). If you had your project in source control, there would not be any question about exactly what had been changed, when, and by whom.

Comment: Thanks David.  Actually I am rather new to all this and am using SVN (Visual SVN Server) and my SVN client is Versions (Mac OS X). I put the original project into SVN about 2 weeks ago and just today he is updating it.  So using that I should be able to see the code differences shouldn't I?

Answer (score 8):

you can use FileMerge. it is under Developer/Applications/Utilities/FileMerge

Comment: Oh this is good too, never knew that was hiding there.  Thanks Mauricio.